# Serialize Dictionary<string, string> with key having object structure

Tags: .net, serialization

Let's say I have the following complex object :

```
public class Customer
    {
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public class Contact
        {
            public string Adresse { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And I've got a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the following data :

[image]

How can I serialize this dictionary to have the following json string ? :

```
{
   "Contacts":[
      {
         "Adresse":"39 Dummy Street",
         "Email":"dummymail_1@dummy.com"
      },
      {
         "Adresse":"455 Dummy Street",
         "Email":"dummymail_2@dummy.com"
      },
      {
         "Adresse":"72 Dummy Street",
         "Email":"dummymail_3@dummy.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You will have to populate the `Custommer` object with the Contact instances from your dictionary. I don't understand your dictionary, however. Is the key of the dictionary actually `"custommer.contacts[0].adresse"`, as a *string*? Do you intend to use reflection to discover that this string refers to the `Adresse` property?

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that a `Dictionary<string, string>` cannot have a complex object as its key. It has a string.

Comment: Lasse V.Karlsen, custommer.contacts[0].adresse is the key and it is a string.

Comment: How about `new Custommer
    {
        Contacts = dictionary.Values.Select(a => new Custommer.Contact { Adresse = a }).ToList()
    };` ?

Comment: To make the example simple, I just added one property "Adresse", but actually the object can be more complex. I updated the question adding the property "Email".

Comment: Well, then you have to parse the key of that dictionary, and put the property values on the right objects. You can use a regex to pick apart the key and obtain the index number and the property name, then add enough contacts for the highest index, and use the property name from the key to decide which actual property to store the value in.

Comment: I will  try to do it this way.Thank you for your response and time Lasse.

Comment: See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uU2lz1 - Be aware that if you're skipping numbers, like your dictionary contains [0], [1] and then [3], it will add a contact for [2] but not populate it with values, nor is there any error checking that you got all the properties for a contact.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Can you please add a reply with a link to 
 dotnetfiddle.net/uU2lz1  so I can accept the response ?

Comment: I added my code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want, now that you've provided a more full question, you will need to do the following steps:

1. For each key, extract the index number and the property name
2. Then, make sure you have a Contact object inside the Contacts list, for the `[index]` index, according to the index you found in point 1
3. Using the property name from the key, assign the value from the dictionary related to the key to the right property on the relevant Contact object

Here's a piece of code that will do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["customer.contacts[0].adresse"] = "39 Dummy Street",
        ["customer.contacts[0].email"] = "customer39@domain.com",
        ["customer.contacts[1].adresse"] = "455 Dummy Street",
        ["customer.contacts[1].email"] = "customer455@domain.com",
        ["customer.contacts[2].adresse"] = "72 Dummy Street",
        ["customer.contacts[2].email"] = "customer72@domain.com",
    };

    var c = new Customer { Contacts = new List<Customer.Contact>() };
    var re = new Regex(@"^customer.contacts\[(?<idx>\d+)\]\.(?<prop>.*)$");
    foreach (var (key, value) in dict)
    {
        var ma = re.Match(key);
        if (!ma.Success)
            continue;

        int index = int.Parse(ma.Groups["idx"].Value);
        string prop = ma.Groups["prop"].Value;

        while (index >= c.Contacts.Count)
            c.Contacts.Add(new Customer.Contact());

        switch (prop)
        {
            case "adresse":
                c.Contacts[index].Adresse = value;
                break;
                
            case "email":
                c.Contacts[index].Email = value;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public class Contact
    {
        public string Adresse { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can see it in action here on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uU2lz1).

The output of the above will be:

```
{
  "Contacts": [
    {
      "Adresse": "39 Dummy Street",
      "Email": "customer39@domain.com"
    },
    {
      "Adresse": "455 Dummy Street",
      "Email": "customer455@domain.com"
    },
    {
      "Adresse": "72 Dummy Street",
      "Email": "customer72@domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Be aware of the following:

1. If your keys skip an index you will get empty Contact objects in the Contacts collection. There will be an instance there, but none of the properties have been set. Example, your dictionary has keys for [0], [1] and [3], but missing [2]. There will be a Contact object for [2], but it will have default property values.
2. There is no error checking that you're setting all the properties on any of the Contact objects. For instance, it is enough that you have a `"customer.contacts[2].xyz"` to get a Contact object for index [2], but property name `"xyz"` won't match anything, and if you don't have any other mentions of [2], both Adresse and Email will be left empty.

Comment: @marc_s *sigh* Can you please fix the screenshot in the question as well? + all the comments? You went through the trouble of fixing the question and my answer, but now the screenshot and comments tell a slightly different story.

Comment: No I cannot - I can neither "re-do" the screenshot (since I didn't do it in the first place), and I cannot edit comments, either